# How to select unique Id in Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am trying to get the unique id from firebase

[image]

```
var likeref = new Firebase('https://myurl.firebaseio.com/' + "/note" + key +'/like');
```

How do i get the path for the key which is -KAoh5I8j9sqFa_BaN4L  so that i get the url

```
https://myurl.firebaseio.com/note/-KAoh5I8j9sqFa_BaN4L/like
```

so i can updated data. Help woudl be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for .key()

```
snapshot.key()
```

Here's a JSFiddle I created for this example: https://jsfiddle.net/lukeschlangen/3chkwhoz/